# Angular 5 checkbox validation in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular5

I am using angular 5 and in the html file i need to validate a checkbox to make sure user checks atleast one box. I am able to get an error but not in the way I require. Currently with the below code I am getting an error message after every checkbox option, but I require just one message after all the boxes.

```
<div class="form-group">

   <label for="options">Categories:</label>

     <label class = "control-label">

       <div *ngFor="let category of initialCategories">

         <input class = "form-control" type="checkbox" 
               name="categories" #categories="ngModel" value=" 
               {{category.name}}" [(ngModel)]="category.checked" 
               required/> {{category.name}}

               <div [hidden]="categories.valid || categories.pristine 
               ||!categories.dirty">
                    Please select at least one option.  
                </div>

       </div>

      </label>

</div>
```

If I put the `div` to show error outside the `ngFor div` then it will show not found error since its outside the loop.

Comment: I deleted and undeleted an answer, so you won't be notified, but please check my answer if it would suit your needs :)

Answer (score 2):

We cannot see if you are using the `NgForm` directive here, but if you aren't using it, use it.

Currently, what you have is just one form control for your whole array, you would want to have a form control for each value. So what we will do is add a dynamic name, achieved by using the index of the iteration.

We can attach a change event on the checkboxes, and whenever a checkbox is clicked, we check if at least one is checked. If not, we set a custom error to the form.

Remove `required` from the template of the checkboxes, import `NgForm` and `ViewChild` so that we can refer to our form when we want to set the custom error. So modify your template to:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <label for="options">Categories:</label>
    <label>
    <div *ngFor="let category of initialCategories; let i = index" >
      <input type="checkbox" name="categories{{i}}" #categories="ngModel" value="{{category.name}}" [(ngModel)]="category.checked" (change)="checkValidity()"/> {{category.name}}
    </div>
    </label>
    <div [hidden]="!myForm?.errors?.notValid">
        Please select at least one option.
    </div>
</form>
```

and the TS file:

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;

checkValidity() {
  let valid = this.initialCategories.some(x => x.checked === true);
  if (valid) {
    this.myForm.form.setErrors(null);
  } else {
    this.myForm.form.setErrors({notValid: true});
  }
}
```

You would also probably want to set the custom error initially, so you can do it in `OnInit` if you like.

Here's a **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-irjxvs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)** demostrating the above code.